# Is it correct to say "don't pull out these bits of wool/cotton"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

My sweater is made of wool or cotton and there are some bits of wool or cotton sticking up on the sweater.

**What are these bits called?**

My children often try to pull these bits out, which may ruin my sweater.

Is it correct to say "**don't pull out these bits of wool/cotton**"?

**Or do we have a more common way to say it?**

Comment: I think they are called 'lint balls'. I would say 'don't pull the lint balls off my sweater'. You can remove them with a razor, or buy an electric lint remover.

Comment: There was a famous TV commerical from the 80s for the [Remington Fuzz-Away Shaver](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8dCjOdoZibk) designed to remove pills and fuzz.

Answer (score 5):

The process is called *pilling* and the bits are called *pills* or *lint.*

https://www.rd.com/article/how-to-de-pill-sweaters/

You can buy small devices for trimming the pills away.

Comment: You know, this is a great, simple answer. I wonder why the OP doesn't select it.